# How do I increase my Ubuntu root partition space with the partition table as such?

Tags: ubuntu

[image]

Partition info included above.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by reducing the size of the /dev/sda8 partition to 140GB as the majority of it seems to be unused. From there, you could move /dev/sda9 (the swapfile) as far left as possible, and expand /dev/sda11 (your root partition) to fill all of the available space.

You seem to have four large ntfs partitions of varying sizes. You might want to consider combining some of these (e.g., /dev/sda6, /dev/sda7, and /dev/sda8); it simplifies the partition table and will make many operations easier.

Comment: But wouldn't increasing my root partition to the left mess us the boot sector and result in the Linux system becoming unusable? That's the only concern stopping me from doing it. Will it be fine?

Comment: You're correct, you will need to reconfigure GRUB. You can follow the instructions here: https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual&lang=C#gparted-fix-grub-boot-problem I've gone through the process before and it's worked perfectly on the first try, but your mileage may vary, so I would recommend a backup.